# iOS8 crash with cocos2d and MKMapview

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, mkmapview

I am working on an app using cocos2d v3.3 and the Mapkit Framework.

When I create a MapView, overlay it upon a scene, and do something like showing my position, everything works fine. But when I pop the scene (of course I also remove the mapview), the program crash. The CCRenderBuffer cause a Bad Access in CCRendererBasicTypes.h:

```
/// Set a vertex in the buffer. static inline void CCRenderBufferSetVertex(CCRenderBuffer buffer, int index, CCVertex vertex) { buffer.vertexes[index] = vertex; }
```

`buffer.vertexes` is NULL, so it crash.
`buffer.elements` is also NULL, `buffer.startIndex` is 0.

I think when I remove the mapview, it clear the renderbuffer, but I don't know why.

Here is the log:

```
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION detected at -[CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized commit] 179 
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION detected at -[CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized commit] 179 
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION detected at CCRenderStateGLTransition 285 
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION detected at CCRenderStateGLTransition 285
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION detected at -[CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized prepare] 170 
OpenGL error GL_INVALID_VALUE detected at -[CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized prepare] 170
```

I tried exactly the same program on IOS7, there is no problem.

Please help me, thanks!